# Breeze issue: null complex type is set to a new empty object

Tags: c#, breeze, asp.net-apicontroller

I work in Durandal-project and use Breeze objects.

I have breeze model that contain some complex-types.

At server side, I set some of the complex-type properties to be null.

But, when object arrives to client-side, the complex-types which I have set to be null - contain referance to object of complex-type.
I need them to be null.

**my main model pattern:**

```
     function addEmployeeType(store) {
        store.addEntityType({
            shortName: "EmployeeDTO",
            namespace: "myServer.Entities",
            autoGeneratedKeyType: AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity,
            dataProperties: {
                Emp_no1: { dataType: DataType.Int32, isNullable: false, isPartOfKey: true },
                employeeBaseData: {
                    name: "employeeBaseData",
                    complexTypeName: "EmployeeBaseDTO:#myServer.Entities",
                    isNullable: false,
                    isPartOfKey: false
                },
                employeeTblData: {
                    name: "employeeTblData",
                    complexTypeName: "EmployeeTblDTO:#myServer.Entities",
                    isNullable: false
                },
                employeePersonalDetails: {
                    name: "employeePersonalDetails",
                    complexTypeName: "EmployeePersonalDetailsDTO:#myServer.Entities",
                    isNullable: true
                },               
                employeeContacts: {
                    name: "EmployeeJobsDTO",
                    complexTypeName: "EmployeeJobsDTO:#myServer.Entities",
                    isNullable: true
                }
            }

        });
        store.registerEntityTypeCtor("EmployeeDTO", null, employeeInit);
    }
```

**server side code** (c#, using apiController):

```
      if (!EnablJobsData)
                employeeData.employeeJobsData = null;
```

I want that when the condition is true, so at client side  employeeData.employeeJobsData() - returns **null**.
Actuality, it returns breeze complex-entity.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Right now all *scalar* breeze complex object properties are treated as nonnullable value types. This decision was made so that queries for subproperties on a complex object would not have to involve special null checking logic. i.e. so that we could use expressions like this:

```
myCustomer.address.city == 'Los Angeles";
```

instead of

```
myCustomer.address != null && myCustomer.address.city == 'Los Angeles';
```

Obviously this kind of expression would get even uglier for more deeply nested complex object properties.

The way this is handled internally is that each complex object has a 'null' version that is simply the complex object with *all* of its properties set to their default or null values.  This null version is the default value for any unassigned complex object properties.

So if you want to detect a 'null' complex object you can simply add a method that checks for this condition.

Note that this is not an issue for properties that return arrays of complex objects.  In this case an empty array is a valid construct.